# Что такое USBC(tw] и другое)?

Tags: linux, usb, вирусы

Решил просмотреть содержмое флешки, используя

```
$ cat /dev/sdc | hexdump -C
```

и в выводе было следующее:

```
003ff200  55 53 42 43 77 04 00 00  00 40 00 00 80 00 0a 28  |USBCw....@.....(|
```

также пролистав немного ниже я заметил USBC с другими буквами и символами.

что это может быть? Пользователь этой флешки использует Win 7 и Win 10.

Comment: Ну похоже на дамп Command Block Wrapper: https://wiki.osdev.org/USB_Mass_Storage_Class_Devices